# how to hide the divs in html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

Hello all i am using jsPDF along with html2canvas. I have seen in the `add.HTML` that you can hide some divs. Is it possible to have this ability in html2canvas.

I am actually making a pdf but i want some divs of the main div to not to be printed in the pdf.

This is my html2canvas code.

```
html2canvas(quotes, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {

        //! MAKE YOUR PDF
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'A4');
        for (var i = 0; i <= quotes.clientHeight/980; i++) {
            //! This is all just html2canvas stuff
            var srcImg  = canvas;
            var sX      = 0;
            var sY      = 980*i; // start 980 pixels down for every new page
            var sWidth  = 900;
            var sHeight = 980;
            var dX      = 0;
            var dY      = 0;
            var dWidth  = 900;
            var dHeight = 980;

            window.onePageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            onePageCanvas.setAttribute('width', 900);
            onePageCanvas.setAttribute('height', 980);
            var ctx = onePageCanvas.getContext('2d');
            // details on this usage of this function:
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images#Slicing
            ctx.drawImage(srcImg,sX,sY,sWidth,sHeight,dX,dY,dWidth,dHeight);

            // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            var canvasDataURL = onePageCanvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);

            var width         = onePageCanvas.width;
            var height        = onePageCanvas.clientHeight;

            //! If we're on anything other than the first page,
            // add another page
            if (i > 0) {
                pdf.addPage(612, 791); //8.5" x 11" in pts (in*72)
            }
            //! now we declare that we're working on that page
            pdf.setPage(i+1);
            //! now we add content to that page!
            pdf.addImage(canvasDataURL, 'PNG', 20, 40, (width*.62), (height*.62));

        }
        //! after the for loop is finished running, we save the pdf.
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }
});
```

Any kind of help would be much appreciated. Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I finally solved this with searching more `about html2canvas`.

You just need to add

```
data-html2canvas-ignore="true"
```

in your html element to hide that div from rendering.

like this

```
<div class="anyclass" data-html2canvas-ignore="true">any data</div>
```

Comment: same me a lot of time. Thankx Cheers!

Comment: @fatpotato glad to help.